# FizzBuzz in Scala

Tags: scala, fizzbuzz

As the title suggests, this is my FizzBuzz implementation in Scala.

I started learning Scala (and functional programming in general) in small steps about two months ago, and one recent assignment was the FizzBuzz task. Here is the simple code I came up with to solve the problem. It runs perfectly, but I figured CodeReview would be able to easily point out thinks I'm missing.

I do think that the hardcoded magic values (3,5,15,"Fizz","Buzz","FizzBuzz") are slightly problematic, but I'm not sure if that's general consensus or what the best way to handle that is.

#### FizzBuzz.scala

```
package fizzbuzz

object FizzBuzz {

  def fizzbuzz(i: Int): String = i match {
    case i if i % 15 == 0 => "FizzBuzz" //because i | 15 is the same as i | 5 and i | 3
    case i if i % 5 == 0 => "Buzz"
    case i if i % 3 == 0 => "Fizz"
    case i => i toString
  }

  def fizzbuzz(start: Int, end: Int): List[String] = (start to end map fizzbuzz) toList

  //assignment requirement: return list of first 100 fizzbuzzed numbers
  def fizzbuzz100(): List[String] = fizzbuzz(1,100)
}
```

#### Main.scala (sample usage of FizzBuzz object)

```
package fizzbuzz

object main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
     FizzBuzz.fizzbuzz100() map println
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Rosetta Code doesn't always provide the most idiomatic code for each language, look at the ["idiomatic solution"](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/FizzBuzz#Idiomatic_scala_code):

```
object FizzBuzz extends App {
  1 to 100 foreach { n =>
    println((n % 3, n % 5) match {
      case (0, 0) => "FizzBuzz"
      case (0, _) => "Fizz"
      case (_, 0) => "Buzz"
      case _ => n
    })
  }
}
```

Your code doesn't use pattern matching well (it is kind of unecesary the way you use it). I would advise you take the solution you have and rewrite it to use pattern matching more like the Rosetta Code solution.

Comment: Thanks for the pattern matching tip; I was looking for a better way to use it and this is it.